# How do I get the exit status when using the sed command?

Tags: command-line, sed

The `grep` command gives out an exit status:

```
$echo "foo.bar" | grep -o foo
foo
$echo $?
0
$echo "foo.bar" | grep -o pop
$echo $?
1
```

But I need to use `sed` and I realized that it has no exit status:

```
$echo "foo.bar" | sed 's/bar.*$//'
foo.
$echo $?
0
$echo "foo.bar" | sed 's/pop.*$//'
foo.bar
$echo $?
0
```

I know that I should play around with the `-q` option, but I have not succeeded.

Comment: Note that `sed` most certainly does have an exit status, it just doesn't do what you need here. If the `sed` command fails, for example, if you try to run it on a file you don't have write access to or one that doesn't exist, `sed` will exit with a non-0 exit status. The exit status just indicates whether `sed` managed to do what you told it to do, and `echo "foo.bar" | sed 's/pop.*$//'` was correctly executed. It deleted all lines with `pop`. That there were no such lines is irrelevant, the command still worked.

Comment: @Zanna I was going to post an answer, but I felt this doesn't actually answer the question. It only explains a misconception, but doesn't provide a helpful solution like steeldriver has below. So a comment seemed more appropriate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use q*n* to quit with exit status *n* - but to make that useful, you will also need to use some [Branching and Flow Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Branching-and-flow-control):

> t
>  
>   branch conditionally (that is: jump to a label) only if a `s///`
>   command has succeeded since the last input line was read or another
>   conditional branch was taken.

It is probably best to choose a value for *n* that is distinct from one of the standard exit status values:

> An exit status of zero indicates success, and a nonzero value
>   indicates failure.  GNU 'sed' returns the following exit status error
>   values:
>
> ```
> 0
>  Successful completion.
>
> 1
>  Invalid command, invalid syntax, invalid regular expression or a
>  GNU 'sed' extension command used with '--posix'.
>
> 2
>  One or more of the input file specified on the command line could
>  not be opened (e.g.  if a file is not found, or read permission is
>  denied).  Processing continued with other files.
>
> 4
>  An I/O error, or a serious processing error during runtime, GNU
>  'sed' aborted immediately.
> ```

So for example

```
$ echo "foo.bar" | sed 's/bar.*$//; t; q42' ; echo $? 
foo.
0
```

whereas

```
$ echo "foo.bar" | sed 's/baz.*$//; t; q42' ; echo $? 
foo.bar
42
```

If you want to omit the default printing of the pattern space, then replace `q` by `Q` (note that `Q` is a GNU extension).

Comment: Doesn't work for multiline file `sed -i` where replacement is somewhere i middle, only works for single-line patterns. Any idea how to use in a multiline file scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to search regex with sed, and **highlight matches**, or **return exit code** (5) if no match found:

This is input.txt:

```
hello there
my dear old friend
a lot of things
we'll pass along the end
```

Here's my function to Print all + Highlight matches + Return exit code:

```
highlight()
{
  pattern=$1
  shift
  sed '/'"${pattern}"'/,${s//\x1b[32m&\x1b[0m/g;b};$q5' "$@"
}
```

> $ highlight "lo\|end" input.txt || echo -e "\n* No match found *"
>
> hel**lo** there
>   my dear old fri**end**
>   a **lo**t of things
>   we'll pass a**lo**ng the **end**

When there's no match, it will return exit code (5). You can **use it with cat and pipe |** as well:

> $ cat input.txt | highlight "hot\|and" || echo -e "\n* No match found *"
>
> hello there
>   my dear old friend
>   a lot of things
>   we'll pass along the end

*** No match found ***

Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405725/43233 - I'm using it + sed quit option.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61808364/10440128

```sh
#!/bin/sh

read -d '' input <<EOF
a
b
EOF

echo "replace yes:"
echo "$input" >input.txt
sed -i 's/a/x/ w /dev/stdout' input.txt

echo "replace no:"
echo "$input" >input.txt
sed -i 's/z/x/ w /dev/stdout' input.txt
```

output:

```
replace yes:
x
replace no:
```

so, to check if sed did replace something:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

read -d '' input <<EOF
a
b
EOF

echo "$input" >input.txt
if [ -z "$(sed -i 's/a/x/w /dev/stdout' input.txt)" ]
then echo "replace no" # -z = "zero string"
else echo "replace yes"
fi

echo "$input" >input.txt
if [ -n "$(sed -i 's/z/x/w /dev/stdout' input.txt)" ]
then echo "replace yes" # -n = "nonzero string"
else echo "replace no"
fi
```

output:

```
replace yes
replace no
```

limitation: can handle only one substitution. so this does not work:

```
sed -i 's,a,b, w /dev/stdout ; s,b,a, w /dev/stdout' input.txt
```

error:

```
sed: couldn't open file /dev/stdout ; s,b,a, w /dev/stdout: No such file or directory
```

(sed treats everything after `w` as a file path)

workaround: use multiple sed calls

```sh
#!/bin/sh

read -d '' input <<EOF
a
b
EOF

echo "$input" >input.txt
if [ -n "$(
  sed -i 's/a/x/w /dev/stdout' input.txt &&
  sed -i 's/x/a/w /dev/stdout' input.txt
)" ]
then echo "replace yes"
else echo "replace no"
fi
```